# How do I configure Simon speech recognition?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, simon

I installed simon (speech recognition tool) from Synaptic.  I am using Lubuntu Xenial.  I have wasted a night trying to get it to work and still have no clue what it wants me to do.

The first time I started simon it tried to lead me through the configuration.  I have never been able to get back to that.  Now when I start it, I am thrown straight in to its main dialog.

I discovered I have to install libqt4-sql-sqlite.  Did that.

I try setting up from the main dialog: settings | configure simon... | speech model.  I would like to set a speech model.  I click open model | download and get a bunch of desktop themes displayed.  I type EN/VF in the search bar.  I see something that looks like a voice model [EN/VF/JHTK] Voxforge and click install, close.  I still don't get any options apart from 'Do not use a voice model'.  As far as I can tell no voice model is loaded.

I managed to download a scenario [EN/H4W] Window Management that appears to do something (it appears in the list !).

Activating simon shows it is hearing me, but no recognition reported and no useful activity of any nature.

Is there any 'Hello world' type setup for this.  I cannot find any clear explanation of what needs to be done.  As always I can find A LOT of information that appears to be for other versions that look nothing like what I see (I tried 'help' but that just says it can't find the KDE help centre - obviously on Lunbuntu).

I am sure people have put a lot of work into this project, but it is wasted if it is completely impossible to use.

Answer (score 0):

That `simon` and `simond` are not running.  You can do this by using the `quit` option from the menu.  (**File** -> **Quit**)

You can verify they are now running with this command-line:

```
$ ps aux | egrep simon
```

**Rename or remove the following files and folders:**

(The first two are folders.  The other four are regular files)

```
~/.kde/share/share/apps/simon
~/.kde/share/share/apps/simond
~/.kde/share/config/simonrc
~/.kde/share/config/simonrecognitionrc
~/.kde/share/config/simonscenariosrc
~/.kde/share/config/simonsoundrc
~/.kde/share/config/samrc
```

**The commands to delete the configuration files are:**

```
$ cd ~/.kde/share/share/apps/
$ rm -r simon
$ rm -r simond
$ cd ~/.kde/share/config/
$ rm simon*rc
$ rm samrc
```

The above steps will take you back to the default, where you will have the startup wizard again.  As far as a "**Hello World**" type scenario, look at the [Youtube steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjJCl72f-Gs)  provided by the main developer.